# JavaScript Array not posting to PHP file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a JavaScript array which is taken from a html form which are Checkboxes. I am using name = "DayChosen[]" to get the data into an array that I can pass into to Ajax. I know the data is going into array as I log it into the console, but it just seems to be lost when at the PHP page. I am trying to gather the selected items and open a new page and post the data to this page.

I have tried to encode it to json and then decode it with PHP, but I keep getting a null value. I have tried using JSON also but still did not work.

I have used var_dump to find that i is returning a null value.

```
   <form> 
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Legal"><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Legal Module</i><br>        
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Day 1"/><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Day 1</i><br>
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Rodent"/><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Day 2 Rodent</i><br>
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Large animal"><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Day 2 Large animal </i><br>
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Aquatic"><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Day 2 Aquatic</i><br>
    <input type = "checkbox" class="CourseDay" name = "DayChosen[]"  value = "Wildlife"><i class="checkbox-pposition DayChosen">Day 2 Wildlife</i><br>

<select class="Register-Multiple form-control">
     <option disabled selected value > -- Select number of Students to Register -- </option>
  <?php 
      for ($x = 1 ; $x <= 10; $x++) {
         echo '<option value = '.$x.'>'.$x.'</option>';
      } 
  ?>
</select>

     <input type="submit" id = "Register" class="col-6 text-center btn btn-primary Register" value="Register">
  </form>



  <script type="text/javascript">




  $('.Register-Multiple').on('change', function (e){



var courses = [];
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each ( function() {
      courses.push($(this).val());
      console.log($(this).val());

});


$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  '../../wp-content/themes/traffica/Multiple- 
registration.php',
       data: {courses:courses}, // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {

          console.log(data);

              window.open('../../wp- 
content/themes/traffica/Multiple-registration.php');
       }

     });
```

});

Comment: Can you share what is shown in the browser network inspector for this request? Just to check if the request body is there and how its being sent.

Comment: You have a typo. Just remove the closing </form> tag after the last input element

Comment: The form tag I pasted in by mistake. I will edit this. everything else works I Ajax just does not seem to post the Array. ALso, there is nothing showing in the Network tab

Comment: try data:  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").serialize()

Comment: How do you dump that in php?

Comment: $_POST["DayChosen"] holds your post data

Answer (score 1):

You missing on change function closing brackets

Please add closing brackets of on change function

And Please add thees code and run it

```
$('.Register-Multiple').on('change', function (e){
    var courses = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each ( function() {
       courses.push($(this).val());
       console.log($(this).val());

     });

      console.log(courses);

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url:'sample.php',
           data: {courses:courses}, // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {

                console.log(data);
           }

      });
});
```

And php file use to get array

```
print_r($_POST['courses']);
```

Comment: I had the closing brackets in the original code I stupidly didn't include it in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Array can be passed by two methods

```
//first is serialize
$result = serialize($array);
//second method 
$result = json_encode($array);
```

In your case json may fail if the array have non UTF8 string or some other issue then you may use serialize insted 
If you prefer json so you may check char set as UTF8
Give it try and check error.log for any output

Comment: What you have in error.log ? Or do you have proxy server like nginx or varnish ?

Comment: I can get the array now when log it into the console using console.log(data); in the success function but when it triggers  window.open('../../wp-content/themes/traffica/Multiple-registration.php'); it looses the value

Comment: I understand but you should know that window.open is sometimes blocked by browser especially Firefox and chrome causes this function used by auto popup ads type to force browser to open additional pages witch is advertising pages so I think it has been blocked by browser